# Why when I set property in a component it starts throwing hydration exceptions Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shadcnui, radix-ui

```
"use client";

const Component = ({ className }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showNewOrganizationDialog, setShowNewOrganizationDialog] =
    useState(false);

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={showNewOrganizationDialog}
      onOpenChange={setShowNewOrganizationDialog}
    >
      <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <PopoverTrigger asChild>...</PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0">...</PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
      <DialogContent>...</DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

This version of code works well. But if I set `Popover` property `open={true}` it starts throwing hydration exception.

```
"use client";

const Component = ({ className }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showNewOrganizationDialog, setShowNewOrganizationDialog] =
    useState(false);

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={showNewOrganizationDialog}
      onOpenChange={setShowNewOrganizationDialog}
    >
      <Popover open={true} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <PopoverTrigger asChild>...</PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0">...</PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
      <DialogContent>...</DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

> Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.

The components diplayed are used in Nextjs app using shadcn/ui.

Comment: How is that message a 'hydration exception'?

Comment: @user207421 Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>. I have added a message under the code examples.

Comment: Maybe you can use `suppressHydrationWarning` if you are sure that is expected to work ... I guess it is because of the state of attribute from default `false` is changed to `true` on server and after hydrated ...

Comment: @KcH yes you are right. I checked the Popover component and it seems like it additionally checks if the open state is correctly set (which is not in my case cuz I set it to true for testing purposes) and on hydration step it sees that it is different from what  it supposed to be.

Comment: I still don’t understand ‘hydration’. That means adding water to me.

Answer (score 1):

turn off ssr by dynamic import and set ssr to false in options.

For example:

```
const Dialog = dynamic(() => import('from-your-path'), {ssr: false});
```

Comment: but why it works this way? btw I forgot to mention that I use "use client" directive in the top of my file

Comment: Client components do run both in server and client. So when it tried to render on the server maybe some of the elements didn't create properly, I cannot say what is happening in your case, But it seems the server and client rendered result did not match, so you turned off SSR, and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid hydration error:

```js
"use client";

const Component = ({ className }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showNewOrganizationDialog, setShowNewOrganizationDialog] =
    useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(true);
  }, [])

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={showNewOrganizationDialog}
      onOpenChange={setShowNewOrganizationDialog}
    >
      <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <PopoverTrigger asChild>...</PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0">...</PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
      <DialogContent>...</DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```